# Managing timezone in php with ics date/time format

Tags: php, date, time, icalendar

Ok, I'm using an ICS parser utility to parse google calendar ICS files. It works great, except google is feeding me the times of the events at UCT.. so I need to subtract 5 hours now, and 6 hours when daylight savings happens.

To get the start time I'm using:

```
$timestart = date("g:iA",strtotime(substr($event['DTSTART'], 9, -3)));
//$event['DTSTART'] feeds me back the date in ICS format: 20100406T200000Z
```

So any suggestions how to handle timezone and daylight savings time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just don't use the substr() part of the code. strtotime is able to parse the `yyyymmddThhiissZ` formatted string and interprets the Z as timezone=utc.

e.g.

```
$event = array('DTSTART'=>'20100406T200000Z');
$ts = strtotime($event['DTSTART']);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
echo date(DateTime::RFC1123, $ts), "\n";

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo date(DateTime::RFC1123, $ts), "\n";
```

prints

```
Tue, 06 Apr 2010 22:00:00 +0200
Tue, 06 Apr 2010 16:00:00 -0400
```

edit: or use the [DateTime](http://docs.php.net/class.datetime) and DateTimezone classes

```
$event = array('DTSTART'=>'20100406T200000Z');
$dt = new DateTime($event['DTSTART']);

$dt->setTimeZone( new DateTimezone('Europe/Berlin') );
echo $dt->format(DateTime::RFC1123), "\n";

$dt->setTimeZone( new DateTimezone('America/New_York') );
echo $dt->format(DateTime::RFC1123), "\n";
```

(output is the same)

Comment: using date(DateTime::RFC1123, $ts) it prints: Fri, 21 Aug 1970 10:26:52 -0500 for "20100406T200000Z"

Comment: In fact for all dates using "20100406T200000Z" format, it is outputting Fri, 21 Aug 1970 with the only thing that is changing is the time. That is why I went to the substr method, so I could get the right time. Is it a problem with my php ini file? This is running on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: I've tested it with php 5.3.2/winxp. Which version do you use?

Comment: Windows NT EQ-610 5.2 build 3790

Comment: I think I've found where the problem is coming up. I'll update here when I get it fixed.

Comment: Ok, I had something else messing with the $timestart string and that was what gave me the aug 1970 output. Thanks for your help VolkerK.

Answer (score 0):

If you've set your timezone locale, you can also then use date("T") which will return the current timezone.

```
echo date("T");
```

Because we're in Daylight Saving Time, (in my timezone) it returns:
    EDT

Then you could use that in an IF statement to adjust your timezone adjustment.

```
if (date("T") == 'EDT')
  $adjust = 6;
else
  $adjust = 5;
```